# RightFax web: sending split faxes or bulking splits ...to one destination

Tags: split, fax, rightfax

I am stumped !  I work in a legal dept for a university, who's client is the State.  We have RightFax, and expect to send @ 100 faxes per day to the SAME destination (our "central unit" for our client).

We are trying to determine if splitting an original pdf to RightFax (for example a 20 pager, to split as follows: 1-2, 3-4, 5-9, 10-15, 16-20) to the same destination recipient is possible WITHOUT having to enter the fax recipient number on EVERY SPLIT to fax.

Or: if it is possible to “bulk” fax – i.e. taking and highlighting a whole bunch of “split” fax line items in your interface and being able to give them all the same “destination” (which is the column that shows up when the fax has a fax number).

It just doesn’t make sense to me that you can’t bulk fax through one interface…

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the COMBINE feature in FaxUtil?  Highlight multiple faxes going to the same destination and right-click on COMBINE - the enter the destination name and fax number one time and it should work.

Comment: ahhh, i will try, but if i'm thinking correctly (which i may not be, b/c well, i've had my head in this too long and i'm getting squirly), i'm not combining, i'm trying to split. i guess bulking split ones wouldn't work, b/c that would be combining. ugh !

Answer (score 0):

according to the directions in the "help" guide: combining would pretty much collect and send all docs in one transmission.

our client needs a multipaged .pdf, split up by pages, and sent/transmitted each split individually (however many pages are within each split).

i hope my description makes sense.

we were thinking, if we have to send many many splits, all to same client/recipient fax, why do we have to enter the fax number every time on each split.  ughhhhh ! is there something we are missing in our approach?  or do we have to enter fax identity on every dialog box for each split, in order to transmit every split?

if so, that's absurdedly repetitive.  isn't there a "save recipient to all splits from the original fax" button?

Answer (score 0):

Will a software like [*DocumentBurster*](http://pdfburst.com/) help you? This software is [free for schools and universities](http://www.pdfburst.com/free-documentburster.html) and (most) probably will handle your PDF splitting requirement. Once the PDFs are separated as per your need you can look into the following options for sending the PDFs to be faxed by RightFax.

- Email the splitted PDFs to a RightFax enabled email address which will further route those documents by fax. The required metadata information (e.g. fax number) can be sent to RightFax as subject of the email or through the attached file name, etc.
- *DocumentBurster* will place the output [burst PDF files](http://pdfburst.com) to a folder location which RightFax will constantly poll for incoming files. The required metadata information (e.g. fax number) can be sent to RightFax through the file name. *DocumentBurster* is very flexible in configuring the output folder and file locations.
- Does RightFax offers a command line interface for sending faxes? If so, then *DocumentBurster* can be configured to call the RightFax command line interface and automatically send each output file to the desired fax address.

P.S - I'm the developer of *DocumentBurster*.